# Magento 2.1: Merge vendor menus into one?

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, extensions

Does anybody know of a way to "merge" extension vendors menu's into a single larger menu?

Reason I ask, is because we have 10+ 3rd party extensions installed in our site, and on the admin page, most of them, want to make their own "vendor" icon on the left menu, and most of them only link to the configuration panel, and maybe one other option.

Is there a way I could write a basic adminhtml extension that "grabs" those menu's and compiles them under one icon menu called "extensions" ?

I'm VERY new to writing modules for M2, so any/all help you can offer/suggest is greatly appreciated.